# SMS alert when audio recording application is running iOS

Tags: ios, audio, sms, recording, alerts

I have an audio recording application. If an SMS alert comes, I don't hear the alert's sound. The recording continues to happen. I can also go ahead and reply without affecting my recording at all. That's a great thing. But, how does this happen? Isn't the SMS considered as an interruption to the audio session?

Comment: I dont think so cause the sms tone doesn't play that long so it might not be considered as an interruption.

Comment: Ok. How does it know that it should not play out the tone when recording is in progress? I mean which function is responsible for handling this?

Answer (score 1):

Pete Goodliffe has written an article that might help you at http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2010/11/make-some-noise-audio-on-ios.html.
Of course, [Apple documentation on Audio interruptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW8) describes the interruptions management.